# Child div closing when clicking on a link

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a horizontal clickable menu using jquery for an intranet.  Everything works fine until you click on one of the links of the child div - this just makes the whole div disappear again.  This is my first attempt so I hope I've explained this ok, I'd really appreciate some help.

script:

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#nav1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#teams").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#teams a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#teams").slideUp();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="nav1outer">
  <a href="#" id="nav1"> Link 1</a>
  <div id="teams"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://child1.com">Child 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://child2.com">Child 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://child3.com">Child 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks
Jayne

Comment: I'm not sure I get your requirements. What behaviour do you expect when a child `<a>` is clicked?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear at all.  I wanted the links to go to another page.  With help I've manage to fix it now using the bind function. Thanks very much. Jayne

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your markup actually looks like this

```
<div id="nav1outer">
  <a href="#" id="nav2"> Link 1</A> 
  <div id="systems"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="##">Child 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="##">Child 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="##">Child 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your code your telling it to hide/show the systems div when you click on any anchor tag within it.

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#nav2").click(function(event) { //Click on Nav2 = toggle child div
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("#systems").slideToggle();
    }); 

    $("#systems a").click(function(event) { //Click on any child anchor tag = slideup system div
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("#systems").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkBxv/)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is bind a click event to the document that will hide the dropdown if something outside the dropdown is clicked, but won't hide it if something inside the dropdown is clicked, so your "show" event (or slidedown or whatever shows the dropdown)

```
    $("#nav1").click(function(event) {        
        $("#teams").slideToggle();
        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            var clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!clicked.parents().hasClass("nav1outer")) {
                 $('#teams').slideUp();
                 $(document).unbind('click');
            }
        });
    });
```

The last part is unbind the click event (shown above) so that it can open again

```
$(document).unbind('click');
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amin and Jeff.  It didn't help that I pasted the wrong code in the first place!  The bind function didn't work at first until I changed the (document) to ("#teams") - now it works a treat. So now I have:
$(function(){ 
$("#nav1").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); 
$("#teams").slideToggle();
$("#teams").bind('click', function (e) {
$("#teams a").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); 
$("#teams").slideUp();
$("#teams").unbind('click');
}); });  }); });